# Android Studio: The Mesa software renderer is deprecated. Use Swiftshader for software rendering

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, mesa

When I run a project in Android Studio using the emulator I get the following error in the debug window:

> /home/me/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_6P_API_24
>
> WARNING: The Mesa software renderer is deprecated. Use Swiftshader (-gpu swiftshader) for software rendering.

The emulator works fine as far as I can tell. It is only a warning but I thought I would try to fix it. The most helpful things I could find were

- [Universal rendering with SwiftShader, now open source](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/06/universal-rendering-with-swiftshader.html)
- [SwiftShader source code](https://swiftshader.googlesource.com/SwiftShader)
- [The Mesa 3D Graphics Library](http://www.mesa3d.org/)
- [Emulator 2.0 Preview Release Notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/emulator20previewreleasenotes)

However, they didn't tell me how to fix it. I'm using GLES 2.0 software rendering on the Ununtu Linux version of Android Studio and the Emulator. I checked the advanced settings in the AVD configuration but I didn't see any obvious changes to make.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I changed a file in this path under windows:

c:\Users\<user_name>\.android\avd\<avd_name>.avd\config.ini

changed property **hw.gpu.mode** value from **mesa** to **swiftshader** and the warning is gone.

Don't know if theres a global property where all new AVD will take it from.

Comment: On Linux the file was in `/home/<user_name>/.android/avd/<avd_name>.avd/config.ini`. Making the edit to **swiftshader** took away the error message that I mentioned in my question. However, I started getting another error "GL error while resizing" so I ended up switching back to **mesa**. This is a different problem probably, though, so I am marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm using windows, but I had the same issue "GL error while resizing".Back to mesa.